# Installing therubyracer 0.12.2 with native extensions - Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

When installing therubyracer 0.12.2 with native extensions, I get the error:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

I tried all methods, like uninstalling libv8 then installing therubyracer. Nothing worked for me.

Command and output:

```
>$ sudo gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'


Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/letsventure/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20191111-5081-xr5qij.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/letsventure/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Users/letsventure/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with 
the libv8 rubygem. 

However, your system version of v8 could not be located. 

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible 
with 3.16.14.19 installed. You may need to use the 
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
    from /Users/letsventure/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/letsventure/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/letsventure/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.2.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.2/gem_make.out
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue? If you know the answer, would you also please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Telling us that you *"tried all the methods"*, without explicitly saying what "all of thee methods" are, isn't very helpful. How do we know whether then thing we suggest hasn't already been tried by you? The most common solutions to this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/issues/266), for example.

Comment: Some side notes: (1) You're using an old ruby version (`2.2.4`). Is that intentional/necessary? It's almost always a good idea to use the latest version (currently `2.6.5`), unless you have a good reason not to. (2) You're installing a gem with `sudo`?? This is a strong indication that your system ruby permissions are messed up. There's a high chance you'll benefit from uninstalling ruby and starting again; following installation instructions carefully so that ruby permissions are on your user, not `root`.

Comment: @TomLord actually I tried all the suggested mehod available on stackoverflow and the reference given by you also but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @TomLord           I am bound  to use 2.2.4 version only so I can not upgrade my ruby version .         I am installing gems with sudo because without sudo it gives permission error may be this is the problem , Okay I will  follow your suggestion and will tell you it worked or not , Thanks for reply

Comment: @TomLord after uninstalling ruby and rbenv and reinstall I get this .Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:
   bundle install --path vendor/bundle

Comment: @TomLord  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.                                           could you please help me how i can fix this problem.